# Android Service crashes on stopForeground if app has been killed

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have an IntentService which is used to save [potentially large] files. I initially had a problem where the service would die mid-save if the app was killed. Starting the Service in foreground during a save solved this problem for the most part.

Here is the problem: If the app has been killed while a file is being saved, when I call stopForeground (when the save is complete), the service crashes, indicated in Logcat:

> 06-23 16:47:25.266: W/ActivityManager(523): Scheduling restart of crashed service...

I have verified that nothing after the call to stopForeground is executed.

It's very possible for me to move my code around a bit, so that this doesn't really cause any problems, but I don't like allowing the service to crash just because there are no consequences...

Because there is no problem at all when the app is still running, my only guess is that it has something to do with the context used to start the service no longer existing. I have tried using both the activity and application contexts, and have also tried running the service in a separate process from the rest of the app. All attempts had the same result.

Am I overlooking something? Thanks!

Comment: By "save [potentially large] files", do you mean HTTP downloads? If so, the DownloadManager is a better option.

Comment: No, it is for saving bitmaps

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?